# Rest service response with activity in background

Tags: android, rest, android-service

What's the best Android architecture for calls to a REST service with the following scenario.

1) The user presses the login button.

2) The application starts a background process and displays a progress bar on the screen.

3) The user presses Home button and the application goes to background.

4) Request ends and the answer comes to the device with the screen still in the background.

5) The user returns to the application and the screen returns to foreground.

How can I get the status of the request, so I can display the data on the screen or continue displaying the progress bar, according to the result?

According to the architecture of Virgil Dobjanschi at Google I / O 2010, it suggests to write to the database and access later. But this involves much boilerplate code. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It really is not a thing of the kind that is ready around, but come on!

If you need to perform some task even when the application is in the background, you need to use a `Service`. With this in mind u could use a Service to make requests and through `broadcast` or `EventBus` communicate the `UI thread` on the status of the request.

Try to use [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) is a modular android library that makes writing asynchronous network requests easy !

**Some main features of RoboSpice**

- notifies your `activities` (or any other context) of the result of the
  network request with respect to their lifecycles.
- notifies your `activities` (or any other context) on the `UI Thread`
- no memory leaks at all, like Android Loaders, unlike `Android`
  AsyncTasks

  **RoboSpice** I believe that is the implementation more closer than you research

hope this helps!

Comment: I talked about this scenario, because when the user clicks login and go to do something else on the device, such as opening another application, when he comes back, he will want to know what happened. Even using broadcast, if the request back before the screen be in foreground, there will be no listeners (considering I have removed the listener in onPause).

Comment: That's right, you need to persist the data of the request and its Activity onResume you need to check will need to register the listener again or get data from the disc do not see another way of doing that is not. Virgil Dobjanschi is certainly better idea for this.

Comment: RoboSpice makes disk cache for solve this question to keep result from request